# New to HTML/CSS, trying to center and display:inline together

Tags: html, css, center

I am new to this and to coding.  Please help! I am ready to gouge my eyes out.

I am trying to have a message centered in the page.  It says "Welcome to Batik Villa".  The page will be in two languages, English and Burmese.  I want to contain a link to swap between the pages.  I want the "Welcome to Batik Villa" to be centered, and the English/Burmese  links to be located to the right of it.  I do not want it on a lower line.  I have been searching for hours, and I am unable to figure it out.

This is my text.

```
<div id=Jim; style="font-family: Georgia;
display:inline">

<p style="border: blue groove;
margin: 0;
margin: auto; 
text-align:center;
color:black;
background-color: white; 
width: 600px;
border-width:10px;">

Welcome to Batik Villa!
</p>
</div>

<a href="b"> English </a>  
<a href="a"> Myanmar </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help! Or tell me if it is impossible!

Comment: For one, `<div id=Jim; style="...` won't work, it has to be `<div id="Jim" style="...` And it is definitely not impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this or am I missing something?: http://jsfiddle.net/SUxmb/1/

```
div.wrapper{
    margin:50px auto;
    width:250px;
    background:#ddd;
    padding:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div#welcome{
    float:left;
}

div#lang{
    float:right;
}
```

Or use http://jsfiddle.net/SUxmb/8/ if you want a centered text box with border that states 'xyz'. On the same line, but off to the right (not centered, and not in the same box or borders)

```
div#welcome {
    margin:50px auto;
    width:250px;
    background:#ddd;
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
}

div#lang {
    position:absolute;
    background:#ccc;
    left:100%;
    top:0px;
    height:50px;
    padding:0px 20px;
}

div#lang a{
    padding:0px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/pD5Vw/1/

```
<div id=Jim; style="font-family: Georgia;">

<p style="border: blue groove;
 margin: 0;
 margin: auto; 
 text-align:center;
 color:black;
 background-color: white; 
 width: 70%;
 float:left;
 border-width:10px;">
 Welcome to Batik Villa!  
</p>
 <span style="float:right; display:inline-block; padding-top:5px;"><a href="b"> English       </a>  
 <a href="a"> Myanmar </a></span> 

</div>
```

Comment: This is very close, thank you.  Only thing is I want the entire text box to stay centered.  It appears to me that it is aligned to the left.  Is it possible for the entire box to be centered and the link to be floated to the right? Or for the link to follow the text box on the same line, but the text box stay centered?

Answer (score 0):

```
<center>
<a href="b"> English </a>  
<a href="a"> Myanmar </a>
</center>
```

???

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want the <a href> centered, I want it on the same line as <p> text </p>, just located to the right of it.

Comment: Ohh ok, use James's code then. It puts the url to the right and the text centered

Answer (score 0):

For div id="Jim" set width as 60% and use text-align: right, which will make the text look centered and float the div to left. Create one more div for buttons and float it right.

```
<div style="float: right;">
<a href="b"> English </a>  
<a href="a"> Myanmar </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For `#Jim`, remove `display: inline`, (making it default to `display:block`); this automatically takes up the width of its container. Then give it `text-align: center`.
2. For `p`, specify `display: inline`, so that it doesn't push the links down onto a new line.

The overall code can be seen at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mLRM/1/).

Comment: Thank you.  This is very close, but both objects are centered.  I want the text centered and the link off to the right.